# Realm not persisting transaction on Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, realm

I currently have a fragment with a listView that I want to populate with records from Realm. On the first run of my app, there are no records, so I created an asynctask to populate the database from a JSON file.

The thing is that If comment the asynctask call `new MuscleTask().execute();`, no records are found, like if the transaction is not being persisted. So, everytime I run the app on my phone when I update the code, the database is flushed away or am I doing something wrong here?

Should I also be doing this in an asynctask, or I just need to create an `RealmAsyncTransaction` and then do something with a `RealmChangeListener`?

My code is not throwing any exception.

```
public static class LandingWorkoutDirectoryFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private RealmResults<Muscle> muscles;
    private MuscleAdapter muscleAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    public LandingWorkoutDirectoryFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static LandingWorkoutDirectoryFragment newInstance() {
        LandingWorkoutDirectoryFragment fragment = new LandingWorkoutDirectoryFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        muscles = getRealm().allObjects(Muscle.class);
        new MuscleTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_landing_workout_directory, container, false);
        listView =  (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_display_exercises);
        muscleAdapter = new MuscleAdapter(getActivity(), muscles, true);
        listView.setAdapter(muscleAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Di click", String.valueOf(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayExerciseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("muscleId", muscles.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("muscleName", muscles.get(position).getName());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    private class MuscleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = getActivity().getAssets().open("muscles.json");
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Muscle.class, is);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                realm.cancelTransaction();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my muscle adapter

```
public class MuscleAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Muscle> implements ListAdapter {

    static class ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.firstLine) TextView name;
        @Bind(R.id.secondLine) TextView description;
        @Bind(R.id.icon) ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public MuscleAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Muscle> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder  viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_exercise, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Muscle item = realmResults.get(position);
        viewHolder.name.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        Glide.with(parent.getContext()).load(item.getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Edit: This is my base adapter.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public final String log = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public Realm realm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Added my app Application Class

```
public class FititApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Configure Realm for the application
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new     RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration); // Clean slate
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `getRealm()` implementation look like? You _are_ missing either a `RealmChangeListener` or a call in `onPostExecute` (the implementation of either would simply call `notifiyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter) but that's not your issue here - if the data persists, you should see it.

Comment: @AdamS, I posted the code of my BaseAdapter which contains the ``getRealm()`` declaration.

Comment: That looks fine. Do you supply a Realm configuration anywhere? Or do you have a "delete on deploy" option enabled in your deployment configuration? (Going from memory)

Comment: I think I know what's happening, I added my app Application Class, I guess the ``Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration); // Clean slate`` is deleting everything, right? 

Also, about updating the UI, when my asyncTask is done, I should call the ``notifyDataSetChanged`` on my ``onPostExecute``, right?

Comment: Yes, that deletes everything, and even if there is an exception you are not logging it out.

Comment: `Realm.deleteRealm(...)` is indeed your problem. If you were doing that because you were getting migration exceptions, you can chain a `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` call into your `RealmConfiguration` builder. And yep, just call `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @AdamS, this line `Realm.deleteRealm()` on my `FititApplication` Class wich extends from `Application` was my problem. Commenting that line of code was all it took to fix my problem. That line of code dropped my database everytime.